# Getting a mysql error when trying to edit table

Tags: mysql, jdbc, intellij-idea

I'm moving to Intellij Idea from Eclipse but I have problem using the database tool. 
When I try to edit a table I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=501' at line 1
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3206)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.execute(Statement.java:698)
>       in RemoteStatementImpl.execute(RemoteStatementImpl.java:61)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.execute(Unknown Source)
>       in JdbcEngine.executeQueryInner(JdbcEngine.java:378)

I don't know what the problem is and google isn't giving me good answers.

Comment: show us the query which is giving the error..

Comment: @ravikumar The error occurs when I right-click on a column and then press Table Editor. But even when I run a query e.g select * from Application_User